# Strange crash from Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am executing a core data fetchRequest as following:

```
AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext  *moc= [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = objAppDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:PUSH_DATA_TABLE inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *arr = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

But the app is crashing at line `NSArray *arr = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` with the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: ' -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeBoolForKey:]: value for key (UIHighlighted) is not a boolean'

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: This exception doesn't related with CoreData, are you sure the exception is happening on the line excuteFetchRequest?

Comment: Please don't request ASAP/urgency here - it isn't appropriate when your audience is primarily composed of volunteers. They **may** get around to your question, at their leisure.

Comment: The error message says that there is a archived object in your graph with a wrong value type of key `UIHighlighted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved myself. I am using a core data model having an attribute of type transformable. I was assigning dictionary object to the transformable type attribute, in which I set a UIViewController object. I guess, UIVIewController object which set in the dictionary was having a wrong value type of key UIHighlighted as **vadian** mentioned. When I removed the view controller object from the dictionary, the crash got resolved.